# In C++, if I have a dynamically allocated array of integers, what is the runtime of the delete[] operation?

Tags: c++

Say I do this:

```
int* x = new int[n];
```

When I'm ready to call `delete[]` on this array, since it is filled just with integers, is the runtime just O(1) in that the memory is freed but no destructors are called, or are some form of destructors called on each integer?

Comment: _"or are some form of destructors called on each integer?"_ No, primitive types don't have a destructor.

Comment: Often it's not the time complexity you have to worry about, it's the general overhead of the memory management.